# Cast to an integer: "int(k)" or " _ = int(k)"?

Tags: python

From this [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_sequence#Algorithm), I found the codes casting to an integer as following

```
try:
    # let's see if k can be cast to an integer;
    # if so, make our alphabet a list
    _ = int(k)
    alphabet = list(map(str, range(k)))

except (ValueError, TypeError):
    alphabet = k
    k = len(k)
```

What if we use `int(k)` to replace `_ = int(k)`?

Then I do some test here

```
$ python -m timeit "k = '2'" "_=int(k)"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.878 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit "k = '2'" "int(k)"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.71 usec per loop
```

It seems `int(k)` has better performance than `_ = int(k)`

Another question, based on my knowledge, the `ValueError` thrown by `_ = int(k)`. What if we remove this line `_ = int(k)` totally as below?

```
try:
    alphabet = list(map(str, range(k)))
except TypeError:
    alphabet = k
    k = len(k)
```

Comment: The `_ = int(k)` assigns a reference and then never uses it. It won't do anything to protect the next statement, either. What are you _actually expecting_ `k` to be?

Comment: Actually, in Python you only have *conversions*, not *casts*.  If you'd like to check the type of a value, use the `isinstance()` built-in function.  If you prefer to try to *convert* a value to a specific type and then react on any possible exception while doing this, I propose to keep the `try` block as small as possible, i. e. only put the conversion into it.

Comment: Using an idiom like `_ = int(k)` instead of `int(k)` as a statement might well be to pacify a code checker (e. g. Eclipse's Pydev editor or a Sonarqube or similar).  They often complain about a "statement without effect" because they don't see possible exceptions as an expected effect.  Assigning to `_` makes it explicit that the result is to be ignored.  It's a flaw of Python that this then lowers the performance.  But being clear often if way more important than performance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`int(k)` is enough to trigger the exception you're looking for - assignment to a throwaway variable is unnecessary (and the reason why that version is slower).

And you're right, you could remove the explicit check for `int()` entirely since `range(k)` will throw `TypeError` if `k` is anything but an integer.

However, it would be more pythonic to use

```
try:
    alphabet = [str(item) for item in range(k)]
except TypeError:
    alphabet = k
    k = len(k)
```

Comment: Try to keep the try-block as small as possible.  Only the `range(k)` is supposed to be in it.  The rest should be in sth like the `else` clause of the `try`/`except`/`else` structure.  Otherwise you might end up cloaking exceptions (e. g. if the `str(item)` somehow throws an exception, possible in this case by accidental overriding of the `range` function).

Comment: @Alfe: I thought about this as well. However, there is nothing here that could throw an exception (except a `MemoryError` if `k` is huge, and you wouldn't catch that anyway) besides the `range()` function. `str(item)` will certainly succeed since `item` is guaranteed to be an integer.

Comment: It's a matter of principle.  In this case it's just the `range()` function, in others you will probably put more stuff into the try-clause (and neglect the effects until they create hard to find bugs).  Functional programming often leads to putting way too much into the try block because it seems to discourage putting small inner results into variables.  I'd propose to do this nevertheless.

Comment: Btw, I always recoil when I see code like `k = len(k)` which obviously changes the *type* of a variable.  This is bound to make the code hard to understand.  As are one-letter variables (closely related).  But these are fallacies OP already introduced in their question, so I won't blame you for it ;-)